# Ansible - debugging a template file modifications

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm dry running an Ansible role. Part of the role is to deploy a big configuration template (that has a lot Ansible variables that get substituted in the deployment process) on a remote machine. A dry run tells me that the remote configuration file has been modified. Since the file is too big to manually go line over line, how could I debug which parts (lines) have been modified? Thanks!

The template is deployed the following way:

```
- name: "Make changes to the configuration file"
  template:
    src: "config.j2"
    dest: "{{config_directory}}/config"
    owner: "{{ service_user }}"
    group: "{{ service_group }}"
    mode: 0640
  notify: restart service
```

Comment: You could back up the original config file and run a diff between the new and old file.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that require deploying the file on the remote machine and restarting the service? I'd like to avoid that (that's why I'm doing a dry run).

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `--check` for the dry run if not already use and `--diff` for seeing what could change when `--check` enabled

Comment: DIFF is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Great ! You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Deploy to your test system first. (If you don't have a test system, that's a bigger problem.)

Deploy the template to some file and use a diff utility against the original. Several ways to do this: create some differently named new file name and `diff config config.new` or use a (temporary) revision control repo and do a `git diff`.

Further, the list of changes expected should be known. Go through the version control commits of your playbook review the changes. If you pull values from other systems, that's a bit trickier, but there may be queries you can do to get old and new values.

Comment: Sure, deploying to a test env is an idea that could work, thanks. However I was hoping for something different - is there a sort of debug switch / function that would ie. display the template config file after the variables are substituted? That would work for me.